# Phone as bluetooth GPS for Linux PC

Tags: linux, mobile, bluetooth, gps

I have a phone (SE j10i) with GPS. I want to get the coordinates from the phone on my Debian PC.

```bash
$hcitool scan
Scanning ...
        30:17:C8:A1:19:BF   Uralbash

$spdtool browse 30:17:C8:A1:19:BF

Browsing 30:17:C8:A1:19:BF ...
Service Description: Sony Ericsson J10
Service RecHandle: 0x10000
Service Class ID List:
  "PnP Information" (0x1200)

Service Name: OBEX SyncML Client
Service RecHandle: 0x2008002
Service Class ID List:
  UUID 128: 00000002-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000002
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 10
  "OBEX" (0x0008)

Service Name: Serial Port 1
Service RecHandle: 0x2008003
Service Class ID List:
  "Serial Port" (0x1101)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 2

Service Name: Dial-up Networking
Service RecHandle: 0x2008004
Service Class ID List:
  "Dialup Networking" (0x1103)
  "Generic Networking" (0x1201)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 1
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Dialup Networking" (0x1103)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: Music Streaming Service
Service Provider: Sony Ericsson
Service RecHandle: 0x8000001
Service Class ID List:
  "Audio Source" (0x110a)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 25
  "AVDTP" (0x0019)
    uint16: 0x100
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Advanced Audio" (0x110d)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: Remote Control Target Service
Service Provider: Sony Ericsson
Service RecHandle: 0x10000001
Service Class ID List:
  "AV Remote Target" (0x110c)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 23
  "AVCTP" (0x0017)
    uint16: 0x102
Profile Descriptor List:
  "AV Remote" (0x110e)
    Version: 0x0103

Service Name: Remote Control Service
Service Provider: Sony Ericsson
Service RecHandle: 0x10000002
Service Class ID List:
  "AV Remote" (0x110e)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 23
  "AVCTP" (0x0017)
    uint16: 0x102
Profile Descriptor List:
  "AV Remote" (0x110e)
    Version: 0x0103

Service Name: SEMC Watch Phone
Service RecHandle: 0x40000000
Service Class ID List:
  "" (0x8e771401)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 61681
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 2

Service Name: SEMC FRCP
Service RecHandle: 0x40000001
Service Class ID List:
  "" (0x8e771503)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 61691
Profile Descriptor List:
  "" (0x8e771501)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: PAN Network Access Point
Service Description: NAP provides access to internet for one connecting PANu
Service RecHandle: 0x1000003
Service Class ID List:
  "Network Access Point" (0x1116)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 15
  "BNEP" (0x000f)
    Version: 0x0100
    SEQ8: 0 6 dd
Language Base Attr List:
  code_ISO639: 0x656e
  encoding:    0x6a
  base_offset: 0x100
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Network Access Point" (0x1116)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: PAN user
Service Description: PANu can connect to a Network Access Point to gain access to internet
Service RecHandle: 0x1000004
Service Class ID List:
  "PAN User" (0x1115)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 15
  "BNEP" (0x000f)
    Version: 0x0100
    SEQ8: 0 6 dd
Language Base Attr List:
  code_ISO639: 0x656e
  encoding:    0x6a
  base_offset: 0x100
Profile Descriptor List:
  "PAN User" (0x1115)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: SEMC HLA
Service RecHandle: 0x40000002
Service Class ID List:
  "" (0x8e771301)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 61689
  "" (0x8e770300)
Profile Descriptor List:
  "" (0x8e771303)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: SEMC OBP
Service RecHandle: 0x40000003
Service Class ID List:
  "" (0x8e771602)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 61685
  "" (0x8e770300)
Profile Descriptor List:
  "" (0x8e771601)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: Hands-Free Gateway
Service RecHandle: 0x2008005
Service Class ID List:
  "Handsfree Audio Gateway" (0x111f)
  "Generic Audio" (0x1203)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 5
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Handsfree" (0x111e)
    Version: 0x0105

Service Name: Headset Gateway
Service RecHandle: 0x2008006
Service Class ID List:
  "Headset Audio Gateway" (0x1112)
  "Generic Audio" (0x1203)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 4
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Headset" (0x1108)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: OBEX Object Push
Service RecHandle: 0x2008007
Service Class ID List:
  "OBEX Object Push" (0x1105)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 6
  "OBEX" (0x0008)
Profile Descriptor List:
  "OBEX Object Push" (0x1105)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: OBEX File Transfer
Service RecHandle: 0x2008008
Service Class ID List:
  "OBEX File Transfer" (0x1106)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 7
  "OBEX" (0x0008)
Profile Descriptor List:
  "OBEX File Transfer" (0x1106)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: OBEX IrMC Sync Server
Service RecHandle: 0x2008009
Service Class ID List:
  "IrMC Sync" (0x1104)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 8
  "OBEX" (0x0008)
Profile Descriptor List:
  "IrMC Sync" (0x1104)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: Phonebook Access PSE
Service RecHandle: 0x200800a
Service Class ID List:
  "Phonebook Access - PSE" (0x112f)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 11
  "OBEX" (0x0008)
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Phonebook Access" (0x1130)
    Version: 0x0100
```

I use a serial port channel 2. My setting from /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.comm

```bash
$cat /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf
rfcomm0 {
    # Automatically bind the device at startup
    bind yes;

    # Bluetooth address of the device
    device 30:17:C8:A1:18:BF;

    # RFCOMM channel for the connection
    channel 2;

    # Description of the connection
        comment "SE Elm (Uralbash)";
}
```

Next I try to connect to serial port.

```bash
$sudo rfcomm bind rfcomm0
$rfcomm
rfcomm0: 30:17:C8:A1:18:BF channel 2 clean
$sudo cat /dev/rfcomm0
cat: /dev/rfcomm0: Host is down
$sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
[ ok ] Stopping bluetooth: /usr/sbin/bluetoothd.
[ ok ] Starting bluetooth: bluetoothd.
$sudo cat /dev/rfcomm0
cat: /dev/rfcomm0: Host is down

$sudo rfcomm release 0

$sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
[ ok ] Stopping bluetooth: /usr/sbin/bluetoothd.
[ ok ] Starting bluetooth: bluetoothd.

$rfcomm show 0
rfcomm0: 30:17:C8:A1:18:BF channel 2 clean

$rfcomm connect 0
Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Host is down
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried opening the serial port using a serial terminal program (e.g. minicom or similar) and issuing an AT command? My first debugging step would be to try that to verify that the bluetooth serial connection is working ok.

Comment: I'm try $sudo minicom And get minicom: cannot open /dev/rfcomm0: Host is down